# Aggregation function on Play Framework / ebeans

Tags: playframework, ebean

i want to get the sum of a field on a list of entities.

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @Id
    private Long id
    private int countfield;

    public static Finder<Long, A> find = new Finder<Long,A>(A.class);
}
```

For example:

```
public static int findCountFieldSum(int stuff){
    return find.where().lt("id",stuff).findSum("countfield");
}
```

Or similar, with a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(countfield) WHERE ... STUFF
```

I don't know if i can build a similar query or something.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your problema fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RawSql](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/RawSql.html) is the way to go. Should be something like this:

```
Query<Integer> query = Ebean.createQuery(Integer.class);

String sql = "SELECT SUM(countField) FROM a WHERE id = :id";
query.setRawSql(RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create());
query.setParameter("id", id);
Integer count = query.findUnique();
```

Comment: Thanks, i could fix it using a query.